# Ant copy with exclusion pattern does not seem to work

Tags: ant, copy

The following Ant snippet should work:

```
    ...
    <mkdir dir="${web.build.war.dir}/WEB-INF/classes"/>
    <copy todir="${web.build.war.dir}/WEB-INF/classes">
        <fileset dir="${web.build.classes.dir}">
            <exclude name="**/pos/**" />
        </fileset>
    </copy>
    ...
```

It should copy every file from `${web.build.classes.dir}` to `${web.build.war.dir}/WEB-INF/classes` except those files that have `/pos/` in their path.

But for some reason, when I do `find build` on the project, I get output that looks something like this:

```
...
build/war/WEB-INF/classes/my/path/to/pos
build/war/WEB-INF/classes/my/path/to/pos/Class1.class
build/war/WEB-INF/classes/my/path/to/pos/Class2.class
build/war/WEB-INF/classes/my/path/to/pos/Class3.class
build/war/WEB-INF/classes/my/path/to/pos/Class4.class
build/war/WEB-INF/classes/my/path/to/pos/Class5.class
build/war/WEB-INF/classes/my/path/to/pos/Class6.class
...
```

Every other similar copy operation appeared to work just fine.

Comment: The `<war>` task is designed for this.

Comment: You're right, but I'm trying to fix an existing build script that is trying to do a whole lot more than the standard war task.

Comment: Another reason for not using `<war>` task is that I am trying to create an exploded war, but `<war>` task wants to create a war archive.

Comment: I understand.  So, `<war>` followed by `<unwar>` won't work for you.

Comment: Could it be that those files were there before the build?

Comment: yes, that was basically it - read the longer version in my answer.

Comment: @EricJablow: I tried `war` followed by `unwar` -- the resulting code was much cleaner, but the unfortunate effect of that move was that dependencies from maven did not get flattened in the war archive.

Comment: The `<classes>`, `<lib>`,  `<metainf>`, and `<webinf>` elements of the `<war>` task are all `Fileset`s. These can take `mapper`s.  Could you have used `<flattenmapper>`?

Comment: Got this error on build: _build.xml:175: lib doesn't support the nested "flattenmapper" element._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eh, in the end, the answer was quite obvious in hindsight.

In the original question I had omitted some of the tasks from the target for the sake of brevity. Appears, I should have not.

More complete snippet would have been this:

```
    ...
    <mkdir dir="${web.build.war.dir}"/>
    <copy todir="${web.build.war.dir}">
        <fileset dir="${web.src.web.dir}">
            <exclude name="**/pos/**"/>
            <exclude name="security/**"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>

    <mkdir dir="${web.build.war.dir}/WEB-INF/classes"/>
    <copy todir="${web.build.war.dir}/WEB-INF/classes">
        <fileset dir="${web.build.classes.dir}">
            <exclude name="**/pos/**" />
        </fileset>
    </copy>
    ...
```

The first copy task would copy all the resources from the development copy of the web resources to the *war-to-be* folder.

I was using Eclipse IDE and as the project was configured to build java classes to the `${web.src.web.dir}/WEB-INF/classes` folder, the first task simply copied all of the classes to the war folder and thus the exclusion filter in the next copy task had no effect.